# autoreconf ignores AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I have a minimal configure.ac file:

```
AC_INIT([phmf], [0.1])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_OUTPUT([Makefile])
```

Using the most current `autoconf` version 2.69 on it (which is 2012 btw) I am receiving the following warning:

```
$ autoreconf -iv
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
aclocal-1.15: warning: couldn't open directory 'm4': No such file or directory
```

This led me to an assumption that the directory 'm4' is being looked for, because it's the default behavior of `autoreconf`. So I tried to overwrite the default value by adding the following macro:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([.])
```

But this was useless - I still get the same warning. Is it a bug or do I have to do something else to prevent including the directory 'm4' for `aclocal`?

*edit*: I dont have any m4 scripts in my project indeed. And I also agree that I don't really want to set macro directory to the root directory of my project. Therefore the more appropriate configuration would be:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR()
```

because I don't want to include anything, i.e. the called command should be just

```
aclocal
```

without any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If your `aclocal` flags include `-I m4` then your `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` mostly likely should read

```
 AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
```

by setting it to the current directory, I'd expect you're making things worse instead of better.

Do you have a `{root}/m4` directory? (where {root} is the root of your repository)?  If not, then that might be the issue.

Try making a "m4" directory.  It should go in the "root" of your project (the same directory as the configure.ac (or configure.in) file).

Comment: Indeed, if you're not shipping any m4 macros with your project and only putting them into the m4 directory, then it's best to stick a `mkdir -p m4` in your `autogen.sh`.

Comment: Well if I would write my own autogen.sh, I could relinquish `autoreconf` and use my own chain of commands, for example `aclocal && autoheader && autoconf && automake --add-missing`, which doesn't need an empty and useless 'm4' directory.

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning, you shouldn't need to do anything about it, unless you planned on using `-Werror` for automake (and that's probably a bad idea.)

The problem is that you can't override the default of `m4` with `.` due to the design of aclocal (and it would be an automake problem anyway, not autoconf.)